# What language is this? - {"html":"<section class=\"page\">\n\n

Tags: html, ajax

I am helping a friend on his companies website, apparently the person who made it has gone MIA..

Sorry for this simple question and if this isn't the correct forum for this kind of question I apologize.

The main index page loads the content into ajax through js when a link is clicked, simple enough.  But each index.html page is written in some apparent form of HTML that i am unfamiliar with.  Can someone just tell me what this is so i can begin my research?  (I have tried to google, but it strips the code so it isn't very useful..)

here is a sample of the code

```
     {"html":"<section class=\"page">\n\n 

     ...

    "title":"Page 1","next":false,"prev":false,"close":true}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you include more details, we may be able to identify what produced it so you can get it back to HTML. Were they using any libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be HTML encoded in what looks like JSON.

Comment: ah thank you!  happen to know of a convenient way to convert back and forth to standard html?

Comment: I'm not sure... this is generally called encoding or unencoding, so you might look around with those keywords. BTW, if on SO you feel your question has been answered, please click the green check mark next to the answer. Cheers!